# Errors occurred:Technical error: Unexpected response returned by server. Import stopped. - Prestashop 1.7.1.1

Tags: csv, importerror, prestashop-1.7

I'm importing my old prestashop data to new site with updated prestashop (ver. 1.7.1.1). When I'm importing the category csv file I got this error

`Errors occurred:Technical error: Unexpected response returned by server. Import stopped.`

I've got other csv's naming products,customers and manufacturers. So which csv is first imported to prestashop ? I've got bit confused here.
Is there anyone can help me ? Any help is appreciated. I'm attaching the screenshot of error here.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it is badly handled exceptions during the import AJAX request. In my case, it was caused by one value in the feature field in the csv import file that was larger than 255 chars. I solved it by increasing the size attribute in **FeatureValue.php file on line 53.**

The best way how to more info about Your problem is open Chrome Debugging tool where You get more information in case of exception during the report.